# How to use apply over a vector?

Tags: r, arrays, apply

Suppose I have a data.frame like

```
a <- data.frame(col1=1:6,
                col2=c('a','b',1,'c',2,3),
                stringsAsFactors=F)
a

  col1 col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3    1
4    4    c
5    5    2
6    6    3
```

I want to have a vector saying which rows have `col2` as a number. I'm trying something like

```
apply(a$col2,1,is.numeric)
```

or

```
apply(a$col2,FUN=is.numeric)
```

but it always says

```
Error in apply(a$col2, 1, is.numeric) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

If `a$col2` (the X in apply) must be a matrix, then why does the help from the function say:

> X: an array, including a matrix.

The help on arrays says:

> An array in R can have one, two or more dimensions.

If an array can have only one dimension, then why can't a one-dimensional array be used in `apply`? What am I missing here?

(Beyond that, I still would like to know how to find the numeric rows in `col2` without using a loop.)

Comment: `apply` works on a matrix or data.frame with dim attributes.  you are. applying on a `vector` which doesn't have `MARGIN` or dim

Comment: @akrun That's not what the help on `apply` says. Read the description for the `X` parameter again.

Comment: It says `an array, including a matrix.`. I guess it implies dimension of 2 and greater

Comment: You could try `sapply(a$col2,is.numeric)` -- which would give you a vector of all `FALSE` as that is a character column.

Comment: If you check the first few lines of `apply`, it is actually chceking the `dim` `dl <- length(dim(X))
    if (!dl) 
        stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")`

Comment: You could use `!is.na(as.numeric(a$col2))` if you want a logical vector.

Comment: Rodrigo, realize that in some languages, a vector is just a 1-dim array; this is not the case in R, which differentiates between the two. Therefore, `apply(1:10,...)` will not work.

Comment: A vector of mixed character and numeric types will get coerced to all character, so you'll need a different approach anyway

Comment: Usually the types described in the docs have a corresponding function which you can use to check your input. In this case it would be `is.array(a$col2)` (FALSE)

Comment: To be slightly more clear perhaps: a 1 dimensional array in r is possible (e.g. `array(1:10, dim = 10)`), but it is not the same as a vector (e.g `1:10`). And you can use `apply` on 1 dimensional arrays, but `a$col2` is not a 1 dimensional array, but a vector.

Comment: Rodrigo, for example, see that `identical(1:10, as.vector(1:10))` is true, but `identical(1:10, matrix(1:10,nr=1))` is not (same with `nc=1`), so R builds and treats them completely differently. (I admit that I've often been frustrated by this, as it requires more steps in functions that can logically deal with 1-dim arrays ... especially when one sees that `matrix(1:10,nr=2)[1,]` does not preserve a matrix, you need `[1,,drop=F]` for that.)

Comment: The package `varhandle` has a nice function called `check.numeric`. I think that `check.numeric(a$col2)` does what you want.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, it works! I found a solution using regular expressions, but yours is simpler.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Now I just learned that a vector and a 1-dimension array are different things in R.

Comment: BTW: `apply(a[,2,drop=F],1,is.numeric)` works. It is inefficient, as all values in the resulting vector will *"always"* be the same (by definition of `data.frame` columns), and that value is the same as `is.numeric(a$col2)` or `is.numeric(a[,2])`. I recognize this was as much about learning the difference as anything, but I thought I'd provide this in case you had less-trivial use-cases.

Comment: Sure thing, @Rodrigo. Let me know if you have questions about it or if you prefer integer-output or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that even the numbers in col2 are character since when combined with other elements which are character they get coerced to character.

```
str(a)
## 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ col1: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
## $ col2: chr  "a" "b" "1" "c" ...
```

**1) grepl** thus we should use character processing like this:

```
grepl("^\\d+$", a$col2)
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

`grepl` is alredy vectorized so we don't need an `apply` or related function to iterate over the elements of `col2`.

**2) (s)apply** These also work but seems unnecessarily involved given that `grepl` alone works:

```
sapply(a$col2, grepl, pattern = "^\\d+$")
##     a     b     1     c     2     3 
## FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 

apply(array(a$col2), 1, grepl, pattern = "^\\d+$")
## [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**3) type.convert** Another approach is to use `type.convert` which will convert to numeric if it can be represented as one.  Then we can use `is.numeric`.

```
sapply(a$col2, function(x) is.numeric(type.convert(x)))
##     a     b     1     c     2     3 
## FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Great! I used `regexpr('^[0-9]+$',a$col2)` but yours has a clearer output.